# Do we have a sidebar link?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this lady in a sidebar link to parents.SE

[image: Parents Link]

Pretty cute, but have we got one of these for Christianity.SE that I might be able to link onto facebook or whatnot?

anyway, I thought it'd be pretty funny if the old atheists site was still up and it had ads for this site and vice versa.

Comment: Do downvotes mean "I don't like the cute picture" or "I don't want the site to be advertised"?

Comment: I was wondering why this was voted down myself!

Comment: Are we talking about [community ads](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/457/community-promotion-ads-4q-2011)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[I guess these were CHAOS inspired ads.](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234/how-do-you-feel-about-my-site-promotion-ideas)  No such luck here (and that's probably a good thing), if we don't get site promotion that can only mean two things

1. No one wants to promote Christianity.SE
2. Christianity.SE doesn't need to be promoted.
3. Christianity.SE would be better off not being promoted.

I said it can only mean two things because #3 is what the rationale for not promoting this site probably on other SE network sites is and that's not really a reason - it's a fear.

We've got a good core troop, good (and by good I mean effective, yet not overbearing) mods and lots of good Q&A.  We're just missing the clickthru's.  Those Elihu's who show up late to the party to give their two cents and let everyone know what God's really thinking.

Answer (score 3):

There's always the "Flair" like I have on the sidebar of my blog.  Go to your profile page and look for the "flair" tab.  It's not as pretty as the link/image you showed, but it shows your stats and includes a link to your profile on the site.

I'm sure that, being a PHP programmer, you already know how to use an image in a hyperlink, so I'm not even going to go there.  We could probably come up with some image for our site, but I think that for the Parents.SE site, the "cutesy" image is appropriate.

I think that with the serious nature of a Christian site, the standard Flair is more appropriate and professional.  Personally, I'd say we should just stick with that.